# How to Insert a Column in DataGridView on button Click?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have DataGridView having 7 Columns on design time in my Windows From. Now I want to insert a new column in the DataGridView at 3rd Position when I call `LoadItemReport()` Function. I'm Calling this Function on a Button Click. Adding of a column should be happen for once only. If the column is added previously it should not add the column for next time.

Here is my code.

```
private void LoadItemReport(List<InvoiceInfo> invList,List<string> temList)    
{    
    try    
    {
        DataGridViewColumn clqty = new DataGridViewColumn()
        {
            HeaderText = "Qunatity",
            CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell(),
            Name  = "clqty",
            Width = 10
        };

        dgvItems.Columns.Insert(3, clqty);
    }
    catch
    {
    }  
}
```

Now as I click on button it adds new column every-time. I want it should happen only for once. Where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if a column with that name is in the grid before inserting.

```
DataGridViewColumn clqty = new DataGridViewColumn()
{
    HeaderText = "Qunatity",
    CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell(),
    Name  = "clqty",
    Width = 10
};

if (!dgvItems.Columns.Contains("clqty"))
     dgvItems.Columns.Insert(3, clqty);
```

**EDIT** 
 Edited to only create the column if it isn't in the grid, credit to @metrosmurf

```
if (!dgvItems.Columns.Contains("clqty"))
{
    DataGridViewColumn clqty = new DataGridViewColumn()
    {
        HeaderText = "Qunatity",
        CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell(),
        Name  = "clqty",
        Width = 10
    };
    dgvItems.Columns.Insert(3, clqty);
}
```

Comment: The creation of `clqty` should only be done if the view does not contain the column (by name), not before.

Comment: @MetroSmurf my answer should work, but you're right. No need to create the DataGridViewColumn if we're not going to do anything with it.